# How to check if SqlDataSource1 select method returns 0 nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

how can I check if my SqlDataSource1 select method returns 0 count of nodes (rows) after :

```
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What, if anything uses this sql data source as it's data source?

Comment: don't use hard English please ==' you want to say that's not the object I must to check ? ... but I can't check GridView on this step (only after DataBound) but there is no DataBound when no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your comment, what you want to do is check the gridview after you databind for any rows, if there is not any it will just return zero (0)

```
GridView1.DataBind();
int i = 0;
i = GridView1.RowCount;
```

**EDIT after comments:** OK, now I understand.here is how you can check the datasource for the number of records affected, you have to use the SqlDataSource1_Selected event

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AffectedRows > 0) //this is where you check the number of rows!
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //something else...
    }
}
```

The selected event fires right after the select operation completes

Comment: but I can't check GridView on this step (only after DataBound) but OnDataBount Method will not be called after I do SqlDataSource1.DataBind(); if there will be no data to Bound. .NET somehow knows if there a Data or a EOF , I want to know it too )

Comment: No :) That doesn't helps, because it Select method will be called after page render and this method returns old data, for example if there was no data and I click button for data there will No Data warning from old statement. and also I dont think that double render is good idea :S